# Hide or remove navigation items based on user role

Tags: angular, user-roles

I am planing to implement a menu that hides/removes menu items based on the logged in user. Is there a way to use the route Guards to change the DOM or what is the best practice to hide/remove elements from the DOM based on the user roles?

Answer (score 2):

The directives `*ngIf` or `[hidden]` are commonly used for such purposes.

In very rare cases it may be sensible to hide HTML structures and services from the user if they disclose attack vectors. In all other cases you'd better invest your time and money into securing the backend.